# php mail() additional_headers

Tags: php, sendmail

I can't seem to send any mail using PHP's mail() function whenever I specify the addtional_headers parameter.

```
<?php
mail('email@email.com', 'subject', 'message here');
?>
```

Works fine, but

```
<?php
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'From: Me <me@email.com>' . PHP_EOL;

mail('email@email.com', 'subject', '<h1>message</h1>', $headers);
?>
```

Doesn't deliver any messages at all.

Are there any reasons why this might be occurring?

Comment: try using `"\r\n"` instead of `PHP_EOL`

Comment: That was actually my original version (which didn't work), I started using `PHP_EOL` after seeing another post regarding the CRLF issues that sometimes occur.

Comment: May sound dumb, but did you check spam folders?

Comment: You can maybe run sendmail -bp (or mailq) to print the current mail queue and verify if it is stuck there. Possibly add a fifth parameter of "-fme@email.com" on your `mail()` command can work if you are a trusted user, I've seen it work to fix problems so I cannot be surprised if it may fix yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can guarantee that your code works fine `as-is` as I've tested the actual code you provided and got the email sent to my specified email address - I see it in my inbox with a big `message` with `<h1>`. I tested it in a server that's capable of sending an email. Your issue may be your server not letting you or if it's a localhost you may need to set it up with a SMTP server- if it is indeed sending, worth a try to check your spam folder ;p

[image]

Comment: As I said, the first one works, the second one doesnt, and I can duplicate the problem 10 out of 10 times. SMTP is running, otherwise I wouldnt be able to send anything at all.

Comment: in that case it's still something in your setup as I've got the code working - the second one in particular.

Comment: Actually, you're correct that the above code works. It seems to be that whenever I add a link in the HTML that's being sent, then it does seem to spam it. But as soon as I remove the link, the HTML works..oh Gmail...

Comment: their spam filter must be taking place and considering your message with links as spam or unsolicited.

Answer (score 0):

> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.

That was from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Do you have a local server (or a remote on if you have configured it to do so) that is **capable** of sending emails? I know that localhost servers might not have the capability to actually deliver the email, only accepting queues.